# How to run a program via powershell as -WindowStyle Maximized. BUT so that it maximizes under the current window that the user uses

Tags: windows-10, powershell

How to run a program via powershell as -WindowStyle Maximized. BUT so that it maximizes under the current window that the user uses.

ex: `Start-Process -FilePath "sort.exe"  -WindowStyle Maximized`

Comment: Try doing the same but inside [Start-Job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7).

Comment: PowerShell notwithstanding. In Windows proper, Maximize means bring to the front/make this the active Window. calling that in PS does not change that. So, you are going to have to grab the currently active app window, then do your app max thing, then, flip back (App Activate) that previous app window. Which means using C# code and/or SendKeys. The real issue here is when you start the script, then the focus is not longer on the original user window, but the script. So, this flipping between things is a real thing to deal with.